# What is the right approach to publish papers in top conferences?

Tags: research-process

I am a PhD student works in Algorithms. I am thinking about the research styles of different people. There are are two set of researchers which I have seen

1. One who solves the problems in cases they work on some leftover cases of other researchers. Their results normally gets published in middle level conferences with lots of effort. For example improving the runtime of other algorithms. They have to understand the previous results deeply and fruits in this side seems less.I have observed that working on small cases is hard and also it is not fruitful many times.
2. Those who apply techniques in other problems for example, some one gave an algorithm for some graph x problem then they will think if we can solve problem y using the same technique. If they are able to solve it then it will get published in the venue comparable to the work they have used.

If I tell you that I want to be productive and want to publish my results in top conferences like FOCS and SODA which of the method do you think will be more effective? I am asking simply what is the research style of researchers who publish in top venue.

Comment: I'll guess that if your attitude toward research is that you want to "sneak by" with minimal effort, that you won't ever be very successful. Work on "interesting" questions. Then submit the work.

Comment: @ Buffy I have spend around 6 year in my PhD and my little experience tells me it matter alot and hard work also but to small extent.

Comment: Neither strategy works on its own - work that appears in top conferences is usually truly novel.  The question is which strategy helps *you* stumble upon something novel you weren't expecting in the process.  Coming up with results that belong in top venues requires luck and talent as well as effort.  If there were an algorithm for success then everyone would be able to follow it.  Since many people try very hard to be top researchers and don't succeed, there must not be an algorithm.